# Beego: how to create an upload form to store files in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, go, blob, beego

I am making an web application in beego. I am new in both go and beego. I want to save a pdf file in mysql database. In php we can easily do that but in beego i am facing issue.

1. Mysql type blob is used to store pdf files. But in go blob is not a valid type. So what should i use in go? I face this issue while making model for the mysql table.
2. How to parse html form to get the pdf file? I know only about GetString and GetInt functions but how to get file type from html form in beego controller?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Beego Documentation](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md), you can use `GetFile`:

```
file, header, err := ctrlr.GetFile("input_name_in_markup")
```

You *must* apply the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your HTML forms so the files get uploaded.

Also, the `BLOB` type can be represented as a `[]byte` slice. Some packages define a `Blob` type that is aliased from `[]byte` - e.g: `type Blob []byte`. You'll have to check the package you're working with to verify it has one. Otherwise, use `[]byte`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes this helps me. But i am stuck at getting file content for saving in database. file is of type multipart.File but i need []byte. I don't want to save this file in file system. Just want to save its data into database. Any help on this?

Comment: `multipart.File` implements the `io.Reader` interface. That means you would read it into a byte buffer as you would with a normal file.

Comment: can you please provide some tutorial link for reading file content through multipart.File. Not able to incorporate this with mysql. I am able to read file content but not able to write it in database.